# Apache: redirecting from one url to another with query param

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, redirect

I have one server that serves two domain: www.a.com and www.b.com
I am having apache and tomcat running on the server.

I want to redirect every request from www.a.com to www.b.com. I want to redirect the full URL, for exmaple:

www.a.com/c/d?someParam=e - > www.b.com/c?someParam=e

How this could be done using httpd.conf or .htaccess?

I tried the followin (that did not work):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.a.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.b.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainone.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domaintwo.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainone.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domaintwo.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What do you mean with that exactly?